# Bad datetime conversion in pandas when a csv file it's opened

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a simple csv in which there are a Date and Activity column like this:
[image]

and when I open it with pandas and I try to convert the Date column with pd.to_datetime its change the date. When there are a change of month like this

[image]

Its seems that pandas change the day by the month or something like that:

[image]

The format of date that I want it's dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd.

This it's the code that I using:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv(directory + "Time 2020 (Activities).csv", sep = ";")
dataset[["Date"]] = dataset[["Date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` infers the format; if that's something already known prior- specify it directly

Comment: you can specify the format during the conversion like this in case you know the format of the date. `pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='raise') ` https://strftime.org/ has list of formatting options

Comment: you can parse dates while reading the csv itself. Try with : `dataset  = pd.read_csv(directory + "Time 2020 (Activities).csv", sep = ";", dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the date format in the `pd.to_datetime` parameters:

```
dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: It was works for me with this format `format='%d/%m/%Y'`